# Adding automatically thousand separators as number input doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I need to add automatically thousand seperators as number input.

I try to write some code, but it is not work. When I programatically set text to edit text it's work fine, but when the user type number thousand separators not added. Here is my code:

```
EditText etEdit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etEdit = findViewById(R.id.et_edit);
        setListeners();
        etEdit.setText("500000");

    }

    private void setListeners() {
        etEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            int after = 0;
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if ((i1 + i2) > charSequence.length()) {
                    after = i2;
                } else {
                    after = i + i2;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                if (editable.length() > 0) {
                    Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile("([1-9][0-9]*?)");
                    Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(editable.toString().replace(String.valueOf((char) 160), "").trim());
                    if (!matcher.matches()) {
                        if (!(etEdit.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                            etEdit.setText(etEdit.getText().subSequence(0, etEdit.getText().length() - 1));
                            etEdit.setSelection(etEdit.getText().length());
                        }
                    }
                    if (after != 0) {
                        etEdit.setSelection(after);
                    }
                    if (!(etEdit.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                        etEdit.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                        etEdit.setText(thousandSeparators(Double.valueOf(etEdit.getText().toString().replace(String.valueOf((char) 160), "").trim())));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

private   String thousandSeparators(double value) {
    DecimalFormatSymbols formatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
    formatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator((char) 160);
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###", formatSymbols);
    return format.format((int) value);
}
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You removed the `textChangedListener` before setting text in `afterTextChanged`, but didn't add it afterwards.

```
if (!(etEdit.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
  etEdit.removeTextChangedListener(this);
  etEdit.setText(thousandSeparators(Double.valueOf(etEdit.getText().toString().replace(String.valueOf((char) 160), "").trim())));
  etEdit.addTextChangedListener(this);
}
```

P.S - You should also remove and add the listener before setting text in the matcher if condition block (to prevent it from getting into an infinite loop).

```
  etEdit.removeTextChangedListener(this);
  etEdit.setText(etEdit.getText().subSequence(0, etEdit.getText().length() - 1));
  etEdit.addTextChangedListener(this);
```